# Pointer value difference not as expected

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, difference

Why does the following code display *4-5* as *4* and not *-1*?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fun(int *a, int *b){
  *a = *a+*b;
  *b = *a-*b;
}

void main(){
  int a=4;
  int b=5;
  int *p=&a, *q=&b;
  fun(p,q);
  printf("%d\t%d",a,b);
}
```

The sum comes as 9 (as expected), but why does the difference come as 4?

Comment: What's the value of `*a` after `*a = *a + *b;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assigns the result of `*a + *b` to `*a`, so after

```c
*a = *a + *b; // 4 + 5
```

then `*a` is `9`, so

```
*b = *a - *b;
```

makes it `*b = 9 - 5`, which is `4`.

The problem has nothing to do with pointers. You would have the same problem if you did it without:

```c
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
a = a + b; // assign the result of 4 + 5 (9) to a
b = a - b; // assign the result of 9 - 5 (4) to b
```

Also note that the program has undefined behavior since `fun` is declared to return an `int` but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks, actually I didn't share the main() code, it's supposed to print the values of a and b there.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure I understand your comment about `main`. You have included a `main` in your question, which is good. A note about `main` though: Instead of `void main()`, make it `int main(void)` for maximum portability.

Comment: Oh im sorry never mind, thought I didn't include main. Could you tell me why the function has undefined behaviour?

Comment: It has undefined behavior because you have declared `fun` to return an `int`, but it doesn't `return` anything. That can cause your program to act very strange. It may crash, not print any values, print the wrong values etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

For starters all these headers

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

are redundant because neither declaration from the headers is used in the program.

Further according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `fun` has return type `int` but returns nothing.

```
int fun(int *a, int *b){
```

It should be declared like

```
void fun(int *a, int *b){
```

As for your problem then after the first statement of the function

```
*a = *a+*b;
```

the object `*a` was changed and in the next statement

```
*b = *a-*b;
```

there is used already a new value of the object.

Instead you could write for example

```
void fun( int *a, int *b )
{
    int tmp = *a;

    *a = *a + *b;
    *b = tmp - *b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `a=4` and `b=5`:

```
int fun(int *a, int *b){
   *a = *a+*b;
   *b = *a-*b;
}
```

This function would:

1. [`a=4` and `b=5`]: the first line sets `a` to 9 = (4+5)
2. [`a=9` and `b=5`]: the second line sets `b` to 4 = (9-5)

Try this instead:

```
void fun(int *a, int *b){
   int temp = *a+*b;
   *b = *a-*b;
   *a = temp;
}
```